# Ownership of table in template

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I've created a PostgreSQL database template that I want users to be able to copy and play around with. The problem is that apparently they don't get enough privileges for the tables that are copied from the template. For instance, if a user does:

```
create database my_copy template that_template;
\c my_copy
create index my_index on a_table_in_the_template(a_column);
```

It results in an error `ERROR:  must be owner of relation a_table_in_the_template`. If I'm not mistaken, this has worked before, but now it doesn't. I'm running server 9.4.10.

Is there an easy fix, or do I need to look for another way for users to copy the database to play around with, instead of using template?